# Git not delete deleted file in local repo

Tags: git, git-pull

I want to find out is it normal behaviour then you delete file in remote branch and use git pull to synchronize local branch,deleted file stil present in local repo?

For example:I delete file in remote repo. Local repo still have this delete files.
Then i use `git pull` to fetch changes to local repo.
I expect files which deleted in remote repo will be deleted in local. But this not gonna happened.

Comment: @matt Yes,files deletion commited.

Comment: Then you have accomplished what you wanted to accomplish.

Comment: @matt it's exactly a problem i want to solve. Files still in local repo after i git pull changes to local repo.

Comment: Stop saying "files in repo". Repositories have commits, not files. If you pull the commit that lacks the file, then that commit lacks that file. It is the same commit and its contents are the same. Done. Of course both repos also still have lots of _other_ commits that _do_ have the file.

Comment: @matt ok. We have deletion commit. But how we pull this deletion commit to local repository?

Comment: @stevemayster the "deletion" commit is pulled along with all other commits when you run the `git pull` command. Like I said, the file will be on disk if you haven't deleted it. If you want to automatically clean up everything not tracked after a `git pull`, you can configure a post-merge hook to do a `git clean`

Comment: @Paolo thank you again. I can insert git clean in script. So i must insert it after git pull command,right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The local repository still has the files on disk, but those aren't being tracked anymore by git.

If you clone the repository in a new directory, you'll see that those files are in fact not present (as you'd expect).

If you want to automatically remove all non-tracked files from disk when you `git pull`, you can configure a [post-merge](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_post_merge) hook to run a `git clean` command. To do this, create the following script named *post-merge* in the *.git/hooks/* folder:

```
#!/bin/bash
git clean -f
```

Do note that this will delete **every** non-tracked file.

Comment: Yes,you right. I want to find a way to only refresh local repo and not to delete it and re-clone after each deletion of the files.

Comment: @stevemayster You cannot _see_ the "local repo" directly. You can see the working tree.

Comment: @matt after i pull changes to local working tree and build artifact it still contain changes  which was deleted by commit in remote repo